# Why include covariance in the interaction model?

Tags: regression, linear-model, interaction, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

[image]

Hi,

The above image is from "Latent Variable Models" by Loehlin and Beaujaean.

Given the model above the structural equation for Y is, Y = c*X + d*Z + e*XZ + W.

So it's an interaction model.

My question is as follow.

Why is the covariance betwen X and Z (i) included in the model despite the presence of the interaction variable (XZ)?

Because we are talking of partial coefficient, the effect of one independent variable on Y when all the other variables are held constant, it seems to be that the covariance between X and Z would be negated by the presence of the interaction variable XZ.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here by definition, the latent random variables $X, Z$ are correlated exogenous source variables in the sense of causal inference, each of which is common factor for several observed variables and also forms an interaction factor for observable $Y$. And note the SEM you referred uses different path as compared to correlation between variables, say $r_{X,Y}$, as the latter uses compound paths. With your diagram $r_{X,Y}=c+id$, while $r_{XZ,Y}=e$. The given correlation $i$ between source variables $X,Z$ are non-causal thus you cannot interpret $i$ as *partial* path (regression) coefficient, unlike $c,d,e$. But from above it's obvious $i$ participates in the *total* correlation coefficients between variables such as $r_{X,Y}$ and $r_{Z,Y}$.

Comment: I'm too stupid to ask this self-evident question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: There could always be something to be transferly learned such as in this case, perhaps it could help you gain more intuition why the tracing rule prohibits more than one (non-causal) curved arrow which the book didn’t elaborate or expound.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Much appreciated!